# HDFS Data Transfer from One cluster to Another is not working with distcp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I need to transfer HDFS data from one cluster to another. I see "distcp" command to be helpful for this case. But it was not. Both cluster Namenode is privately interconnected with other datanodes. So I have two proxy machines to connect publically with the namenode. Say, I made namenode's 8070 port to run under 20000 in haproxy. Now I can ping both clusters namenode. So, I went for distcp option. There the mapreduce job starts executing for the data transfer but it is not completing.

```
[hdfs@ip-20-0-42-252 ~]$ hadoop distcp  hdfs://YY.YY.YY.YY:20000/user/ce_prasith/filter.txt  hdfs://xx.xx.xx.xx:20000/user/gl_qauser
18/10/09 10:12:15 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, overwrite=false, append=false, useDiff=false, useRdiff=false, fromSnapshot=null, toSnapshot=null, skipCRC=false, blocking=true, numListstatusThreads=0, maxMaps=20, mapBandwidth=100, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', preserveStatus=[], preserveRawXattrs=false, atomicWorkPath=null, logPath=null, sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[hdfs:/user/ce_prasith/filter.txt], targetPath=hdfs://xx.xx.xx.xx:20000/user/gl_qauser, targetPathExists=true, filtersFile='null'}
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO tools.SimpleCopyListing: Paths (files+dirs) cnt = 1; dirCnt = 0
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO tools.SimpleCopyListing: Build file listing completed.
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.factor is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO tools.DistCp: Number of paths in the copy list: 1
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO tools.DistCp: Number of paths in the copy list: 1
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm97
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1539063069030_0003
18/10/09 10:12:16 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1539063069030_0003
18/10/09 10:12:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-20-0-21-94.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1539063069030_0003/
18/10/09 10:12:17 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job-id: job_1539063069030_0003
18/10/09 10:12:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1539063069030_0003
18/10/09 10:12:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1539063069030_0003 running in uber mode : true
18/10/09 10:12:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/10/09 10:13:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

For your information I have taken few logs of the job

```
2018-10-09 12:01:42,715 WARN [CommitterEvent Processor #2] org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyCommitter: Unable to cleanup temp files
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-YY.YY.YY.YY.ec2.internal/YY.YY.YY.YY to ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:20000 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:20000]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getListing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:573)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getListing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$600(DistributedFileSystem.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyCommitter.deleteAttemptTempFiles(CopyCommitter.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyCommitter.cleanupTempFiles(CopyCommitter.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyCommitter.abortJob(CopyCommitter.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobAbort(CommitterEventHandler.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:20000]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    ... 31 more
2018-10-09 12:01:42,716 INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #2] org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyCommitter: Cleaning up temporary work folder: /user/hdfs/.staging/_distcp1087004350
```

I get stuck over here. Does somebody have any idea to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have any additional logs besides this ??

Comment: No. I have this mapreduce log only.

Comment: plz run with -log option

Comment: @RahimDastar and Constantine I have shared logged in the post since comment section holds characters limitation. Please check in the post.

Comment: Not all operations are tunneling through a proxy or a Namenode. The datanodes should be able to directly copy between each other. Looks like some of your machines are resolving to internal EC2 addresses. Note: Copying data to S3 and moving data that way would probably be easier

Comment: @cricket_007 copying to S3 is okay. But my ultimate aim is to transfer data from cluster to cluster including permissions which are not with S3 I guess.

Comment: IAM roles could be delegated to redesign the access rights to the files. I'm not sure how well those could be translated into HDFS users, though, but typically you give teams independent, ephemeral "processing clusters" in the cloud, then all storage sits in object storage, not idle HDFS disks that you're paying a lot more for

Answer (score 0):

All nodes in source cluster should see all nodes in destination cluster.

Comment: You should clarify 'see'. For example, machines that can ping each other doesn't mean that other ports are reachable

Comment: Port depends on hadoop configuration and version

Comment: I know, but that does not answer my comment

Comment: @cricket_007 this link is good for cloudera: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/install_ports_distcp.html

Comment: So you mean that I need to open the ports of datanodes as I did for namenode in both the cluster thru haproxy?

Comment: Yes, port number depends on uour configuration.

Comment: @Prasith Not clear why you're using HaProxy rather than a proper AWS VPC between the clusters

Comment: @RahimDastar & cricket_007 I opened the datanode port 50010 (which was in link) and tried to discp again. But still having the same issue.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error but not connectivity error. Can you guide me from here?

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/gl_qauser/.distcp.tmp.attempt_1539234237231_0001_m_000000_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.

Comment: Isn’t your destinatin hdfs in safe mode?!